# Can not parse JSON from MQTT Message in Broker

Tags: node.js, json, mqtt, mosca

I'm building a MQTT Server using Mosca and trying to parse MQTT Message to JSON for database store purpose.

The code in 'published' callback below

```
server.on('published', (packet, client) => {
    let { payload } = packet;
    if(payload) {
        let payloadString = payload.toString();
        let payloadJson = JSON.parse(payloadString);
        console.log(payloadJson)
    }
});
```

Sample of JSON String is:

> {"_id":"5e928105156c40000006f9e9","temperature":33,"humidity":64.9}

But I received an error in line `JSON.parse`

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2

How should I do to parse this message correctly ?

Comment: Could you log the actual value of payloadString and add it to the question?

Comment: Hi @JoachimIsaksson, the log before parse is the sample of JSON String above `{"_id":"5e928105156c40000006f9e9","temperature":33,"humidity":64.9}`

Comment: What platform are you running on and what is the default encoding in use? As that payload buffer parses properly both as a string and directly from the buffer with UTF8

Comment: Hi @hardillb, I'm using Arduino with ArduinoJson 6 for send message. I'm not sure the default encoding but it maybe UTF8.
I have 2 places receive the message, are a broker server (Node JS) and Mobile App (React Native). I can parse the message on React Naitve (both using JSON.parse() in javascript) but can not parse in Node js

Comment: The question was where is the nodejs code running

Comment: I just run on my local MacOS, with Mosca and MongoDB Ascoltatore

Comment: First off, there are no MQTT "Servers" -- There are "Brokers" and "Clients" and they can "Publish" or "Subscribe" or both.  I am guessing that you are trying to build a custom Broker, correct?
Second:  Why are you converting the JSON to a string, and then converting it back? "payload" is already in JSON format, so I don't understand why you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @JDAllen, sorry about my words. Yes I'm buiding a custom Broker. The payloads received in Broker are in String Buffer. An example of payload is: {"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,95,105,......,125]}. So that I need a method to parse it to JSON Object to store in my database

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using MongoDB for your project.

I don't know what's the code on the `server.emit()` side because you didn't provide it.

But try to pass in `.lean()` before getting the data from MongoDB will solve your problem.

Something like this:

`const leanDoc = await MyModel.findOne().lean();`

Check this out as well: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help some one in future
update the code as

```
server.on('published', (packet, client) => {
    let { payload } = packet;
    if(payload) {
        let payloadString = payload.toString();
        try {
            let payloadJson =  JSON.parse(payloadString)
            console.log(payloadJson)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Invalid json data")
        }
    }
})
```